# Redux: is state normalization necessary for composition relationship?

Tags: redux, state, ngrx

As we know, when saving data in a redux store, it's supposed to be transformed into a normalized state. So embedded objects should be replaced by their ids and saved within a dedicated collection in the store.

I am wondering, if that also should be done if the relationship is a composition? That means, the **embedded data isn't of any use outside of the parent object**.

In my case the embedded objects are *registrations*, and the parent object is a (real life) *event*. Normalizing this data structure to me feels like a lot of boilerplate without any benefit.

Comment: I with your last paragraph and Nate's answer is a great one. Have you thought about using @ngrx/entity? In my opinion it's a great in between, simple to use, and removes a lot of reducer boilerplate.

Answer (score 3):

State normalization is more than just how you access the data by traversing the object tree. It also has to do with how you observe the data.

Part of the reason for normalization is to avoid unnecessary change notifications. Objects are treated as immutable so when they change a new object is created so that a quick reference check can indicate if something in the object changed. If you nest objects and a child object changes then you should change the parent. If some code is observing the parent then it will get change notifications every time a child changes even though it might not care. So depending on your scenario you may end up with a bunch of unnecessary change notifications.

This is also partly why you see lists of entities broken out into an array of identifiers and a map of objects. In relation to change detection, this allows you to observe the list (whether items have been added or removed) without caring about changes to the entities themselves.

So it depends on your usage. Just be aware of the cost of observing and the impact your state shape has on that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't agree that data is "supposed to be [normalized]". Normalizing is a useful structure for accessing the data, but you're the architect to make that decision.

In many cases, the data stored will be an application singleton and a descriptive key is more useful than forcing some kind of id.

In your case I wouldn't bother unless there is excessive data duplication, especially because your would have to then denormalize for the object to function properly.